# Should we ask for area code or just the country code?

Tags: usability, forms

When asking for phone number (open to international users), which is better?

1. Have a separate field for area code.
2. Let them choose just the country code and let them type in whatever comes next (area code + phone num.)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Country code should be enough. What if the user inserts a cellphone number?

Here in Sweden we don't have areacodes except for landlines; but even then you might get something completely different.

So **option 2** is best here.

Comment: Agreed. I might make the label on the phone number field say "Phone No. (incl. Area or City Code if needed)", just in case - never assume that your users will automatically know to include it...